# Can't change Image source in code behind

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to change `Image.Source` in code behind.
When button clicked, `Image.Source` is modified in code behind and it supposed 
to display an image in windows. Unfortunately, it seems not working.
Can anyone give me an idea what the problem is?
Thank you.

Here are my codes:

`XML`:

```
`<Grid Margin="0,0,-234,0">
        <Image Source="{Binding SourceName, Mode=TwoWay}" 
        Height="100" Width="100" Margin="201,69,661,151"/>
        <Button Margin="201,215,644,39" Click="Button_Click">show image</Button>
 </Grid>`
```

`C#` part:

```
 private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Uri uri = new Uri(@"C:\localFTP\thisImage.jpg", UriKind.Absolute);

        BitmapImage i = new BitmapImage();
        i.BeginInit();
        i.UriSource = uri;
        i.EndInit();


        SourceName = i;
    }


    private ImageSource _sourceName;

    public ImageSource SourceName
    {
        get
        {
            return _sourceName;
        }
        set
        {
            _sourceName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SourceName");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

Comment: It is not working, what is not working ? You get any error messages, Exceptions, ... the sky is falling down ?

Comment: @PhilipStuyck I don't get any error messages...

Comment: Sure that `C:\localFTP\thisImage.jpg` really exists? As a note, setting `Mode=TwoWay` on the `Image.Source` binding doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Clemens yes it does. If I do `imageName.source = i`, it perfectly works. But I want to implement it without using `Name`.

Comment: Then you probably didn't set the source of the binding correctly. Since you are not setting it explicitly by either the `Source` or the `RelativeSource` property, you'll have to set the `DataContext` of your Window or UserControl somewhere. Try setting `DataContext = this;` in your MainWindow's constructor.

Comment: @Clemens awesome, it works! Can you also tell me how I can set it by using RelativeSource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't seem to have the source of the binding set anywhere.

So either you set your MainWindow's DataContext, e.g. in the constructor like

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();   
    DataContext = this;
}
```

or you specify the binding source explicitly, e.g. by setting its RelativeSource:

```
<Image Source="{Binding SourceName,
                RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"/>
```

---

As a note, `SourceName` seems to be a strange name for a property of type ImageSource. It should better be named `Source` or `ImageSource`.

It may also be worth to note that creating a BitmapImage actually requires less code than what you've shown in your question:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var uri = new Uri(@"C:\localFTP\thisImage.jpg");
    SourceName = new BitmapImage(uri);
}
```